# Flutter, Dart. Interpolators for range of values

Tags: animation, flutter, dart

I didn't find right sources, where this information is described. What I'm already did, it's simple animation of the scroll. Something like custom `NavigationDrawer`.

```
  void setupAnimation(TickerProvider provider, VoidCallback callback) {
    controller = AnimationController(duration: duration, vsync: provider);

    tween = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 0.0);
    value = tween.animate(controller)..addListener(callback);
  }

  void playAnimation(double start, double end, Duration duration) {
    tween
      ..begin = start
      ..end = end;
    controller.duration = duration;
    controller
      ..reset()
      ..forward();
  }
```

And all value changes is linear, even from the source documentation of the `Tween` Object. **So I'm looking for a simple way to setup interpolator for value changes.** After searching the information, I found something similar for bounce animation. Small sample from that source is next. And obviously, this works well, but only for double range from 0.0 to 1.0.

```
  var rectAnimation = _createTween(parentContext)
      .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.ease))
      .animate(animation);
```

Comment: `var ctrl = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), vsync: this); var anim = Tween(begin: 2.0, end: 3.0) .chain(CurveTween(curve: Threshold(0.5))) .animate(ctrl); ctrl.addListener(() { print('time: ${ctrl.value.toStringAsFixed(2)} anim: ${anim.value}'); }); ctrl.forward();` - it does use `Tween`'s `begin` and `end` values, not `AnimationController`'s 0 and 1

Comment: @pskink Works perfect. Add answer, so I can accept it.